# What does this JS Syntax do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Why would I put brackets around the `true` here.... doesn't that make an array?  Does it do something else?

```
$e.trigger("onlyShowIfChange", [true]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .trigger( eventType, extraParameters )
>
> eventType: A string containing a
>   JavaScript event type, such as click
>   or submit.
>
> extraParameters: An array of
>   additional parameters to pass along to
>   the event handler.

The second parameter has to be an array

```
$e.trigger("onlyShowIfChange", [true, false]);

$e.bind("onlyShowIfChange", function(ev, trueBool, falseBool) {
   ...
});
```

This means if you want to pass extra parameters to your event binding functions you have to pass in an array of parameters to trigger as the second argument.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that makes an Array with one element — `true`.

It doesn't do anything else.

Sometimes, method calls may require an array, and if you don't have an Array already, you can conveniently wrap your parameter(s) with `[]`.

A common case is the [Function.apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply).  The second parameter is *argArray*:

```
var func = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

func.apply(null, [1, 3]); // returns 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes an array with `true` as its only value, but probably you have found this syntax in some documentation and in that case means that `true` is optional.